# Google app engine installation using java

Tags: google-app-engine

I am trying to install google application engine using java but could find a way to do it ..i found a way to install using python but not java on windows.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You could give the quick start a try: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/quickstart

Comment: Furthermore, there are directions for installing the App Engine SDK on Windows here: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/download#java_windows.